# Xcode no longer autocompletes #import statements

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Running Xcode 6.3.2 OSX 10.10.3. On my rMBP 2012, Xcode isn't auto-complete statements #import, but my rMBP 2014 is.

It's able to autocomplete code snippets and other code statements.

Not sure what other information I can give, it just started happening a couple of months ago.

Comment: The same problem here. Also, rMBP 2012, OS X 10.10.3, Xcode 6.3.2. It has also been happening for a couple of months now.

Comment: I've got the same problem (OS X 10.10.3 and Xcode 6.3.2). I've tried to remove derived data but it didn't help unfortunately. Some of my workmates run same Xcode version with no issues so it seems to be random bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this bug as well and found that it's only a problem if you actually fully type in:

```
#import "
```

and then try to add the first letters of the file you're looking for, it will not autocomplete at all.  However, if you just type:

```
 #im
```

then you will get an autocomplete suggestion: [image]

and then you can press enter and your cursor will be placed inside the quotes and then once you start typing then you will actually get autocomplete suggestions:[image]

I filed a bug report with Apple regarding this, so hopefully it will get fixed, but for now you can get around this by just autocompleting the #import directive itself.